# End punctuation when using quotation marks

Tags: punctuation

When do you put the end punctuation of a sentence inside or outside of quotation marks including the last word of the sentence?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Michael.  Please check out our [tour] and our [help] to get a feel for the place.  Your question is one that has an answer on the site but do feel free to ask other Writing questions and answer ones you see too.  The quick answer though is, it depends if you're British or American (not sure about other dialects of English or other languages).  Americans inside, Brits outside.

Answer (score 0):

That depends. If your quote is from the middle or start of a sentence to the end of it, then it should be .” If it’s not a complete sentence (not to be end of the sentence) then the punctuation should be ”.